# Local Player Bukkit/Spigot Development

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Are there commands to get the display name of the local player.
So if I create a chat message, all players seen their own name in the chat. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get the "local" player name, because who will run the code is the server, not the client, so you can't get it because there is no local player. However, you can still send a custom message for different people with different names to simulate this effect.

Based in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34636083/7225971) example, you can simply send a message through the /tellraw command to the players that you want to send the message, example:

```
public static void sendMessage(String playerName, String msg) {
        Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(),
                "/tellraw " + playerName + " {\"text\":\"" + msg.replaceAll("<playername>", playerName) + "\"}");
}
```

In this case, I've used `<playername>` as a keyword to reference the player, so `Hello <playername>` should return `Hello yourname`...
However, this solution is better when you don't have the Player object, and to not waste your machine's time to create it, you can simply use the tellraw... But to simplify the answer, you can use the `Player::sendMessage` method (quoted by bcsb1001).:

```
public static void sendMessage(Player player, String msg){
    player.sendMessage(msg.replaceAll("<playername>", player.getName()));
}
```

Okay, but how can I send it to every person in a group, or in an Array?
In this case, you can use a `for each` loop for every single player.

Here is the **full** code to send a hello message to every single player online:

```
public static void sayHelloToEveryone() {
    String msg = "Hello <playername>!";
    for (Player p : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
        p.sendMessage(msg.replaceAll("<playername>", p.getName()));
    }
}
```

Therefore, when you use `sayHelloToEveryone()`, it will send a message to everyone based on their name:

If there are Steve and Ruben online, the server will send a different message to both users:
**Steve's chat:** `Hello Steve!`
**Ruben's chat:** `Hello Ruben!`

Comment: What's the point of using tellraw when you can just do `Player::sendMessage`? You're not using anything that requires a tellraw JSON.

Comment: @bcsb1001 the point of using tellraw is that you can actually specify the player name, instead of the player object, making it easier if you're going to specify them in a command... Nevertheless, I'm going to add this to the answer since the OP is asking for a broadcast, Thanks!